# How do I avoid wrinkles in dress pants placed on a hanger?

Tags: clothing, storage

I am constantly using dress pants for work or other events. I iron these pants in advance, and sometimes, they ended up with a wrinkle because of the hanger's curvature. Is there any type of hack that I can use, so I can hang the pants in a way that the curvature of the hanger does not create a wrinkle?

Comment: Uh, use an un-bent hanger?

Comment: Could you post a picture of the hanger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use pants hangars

Not a hack, but they make [hangers designed for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=pants%20hanger&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_xakVNWOI4WfggT-roSIDQ&ved=0CF0QsAQ&biw=1455&bih=705). Assuming your closet is tall enough, you can just let them hang down fully without the fold. If you don't want to buy one, you can fashion one yourself out of a regular hangar and a couple clothespins. The idea is to just clip the waist to the hangar.

#### Option 2: Duct tape

The main reason you get a crease is because the hangar is too thin, and it's creating a fold. You can thicken it by wrapping it in something. Sure you could use cloth or something else, but duct tape is normally on hand (at least in my experience). Try to wrap it as smoothly as possible. If you can get the hangar bar to a half-inch or more diameter, you shouldn't have much of a problem with wrinkles.

Answer (score 3):

Cut a piece of pipe insulation the length of the horizontal bar on the bottom of the hanger. Since the pipe insulation is already slit along the length the insulation, it will slip right onto the bar and stays on the bar without any further taping required.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out a thicker hanger is better, many dry cleaners use metal hangars but place a folded piece of card over the bottom wire to make them effectively wider.

The other trick is rather than folding both legs together over the wire place one leg over the wire from one side and the other leg from the other side. This allows the trowsers to be hung a little lower as the top leg secures the bottom so you do not have to have the weight 50:50 and can align the bar at knee hight - where you tend to get a crease when walking, etc.